# Get xml unknown data values in a .php page

Tags: php, xml

One of our vendors sends us response codes after submitting information to their database.

They send the response codes in xml format to a URL we specified (http://www.wecaref.com/retrieve_codes.php)

We have a sample of the xml structure but how do we get the values as they will be changing based on the outcome of the transactions?
xml structure is:-

```
<Message date="30/04/2010 17:21:26">
<Version>1.0</Version>
<OrderID>2010043017155067</OrderID>
<TransactionType>Purchase</TransactionType>
<PAN>4278XXXX4626</PAN>
</Message>
```

Kindly note that the values will be dynamic based on outcome of the transactions.

We have tried using SimpleXML but can only get this done with known values and passed as string.
We have tried the following but did not output any data.

```
//Get XML mesaage response
$xml_feed_url = 'http://www.wecaref/retrieve_codes.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$Message = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$orderid =  $Message->Message->OrderID;

echo "orderid is ".$orderid;

//End get XML Response
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: How to retrieve values from the above xml structure dynamically

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? By that I mean post some source code that isn't working for you.

Comment: They said we should make a Request.getParameter(“xmlmsg”); but this applies to Java/j2ee. We would like to know how we can make such requests in php.

Comment: They are posting to a URL you own ? or you are posting to a URL someone else owns ? your script is retrieve_codes.php ? you said Request.getParameter ... that implies they are calling your script ?

Comment: They are posting to a URL we own(retrieve_codes.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orderid =  $Message->OrderID;
```

A simple debug technique like var_dump will show you the above.

docs :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php